# The signature is missing from the zip file. Upload a new zip file containing a valid signature. (Google Play Console)

Tags: android, google-play-console, android-app-bundle

So apparently I'm trying to upload a new release for an existing app on google play console. I lost my jks file but I have requested for a new one and I even got them too. Now when I try to generate a signed bundle from android, it generates successfully but when I upload that bundle as a new release, the play console gives me following error:

[image: App Bundle Upload error]

Now after some R&D and running through some stack overflow threads I came to knew that my SHA certificate of the jks file is different as compared to the SHA certificate on google play console. Moreover, I have tried downloading the new upload_certificate from google play console and overwrite it to the old one of jks file through keytool on console. Furthermore, I tried extracting and uploading new upload key from keystore but it gives the following error:
"The signature is missing from the zip file. Upload a new zip file containing a valid signature."
I have been stuck in this thing since 3 days if anyone knows some legit work around this things do ping me up.

Answer (score 0):

So after 3 days of trying I have finally found the solution. After requesting for new jks file and getting it from google run the following command on windows power shell or command prompt to check certificates registered against your new jks file:

```
keytool -list -v -keystore yourjksfilename.jks
```

**Note**: If you open shell from the same folder where your jks file is then simply change the last part with your file name and if you open it from somewhere else just simple change last part with path including your jks file name. Also to run the above command u need to have java installed on your machine and it's JDK or JRE home environment set in system variables too. If not that just simple change directory to the folder where your java is installed and inside java open **bin** folder and run it from there

you will get an output in which their will be number of SHA certificates registered against your jks file. After that go to Google Play Console and open "App integrity" tab, inside app integrity open "App signing" and verify if your upload certificate SHA is same as you get in console. If both certificate matches with any entry u get on the console, check for it's alias then. If alias of the matched certificate matched with the alias u set creating new jks then you're good to go, just simply generate signed bundle and upload it on google play console release section and if it doesn't matches, change it's alias to the one that you set earlier creating new key by running following command:

```
keytool -changealias -alias your-very-very-long-alias -destalias new-alias-you-want-to-set -keystore /path/to/keystore
```

If you still get confused or not able to upload your signed app bundle feel free to reach out to me